# How to get packages from a Mac with internet to a Ubuntu 18.04 with no internet and installed properly?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, internet, mac

**What am I trying to do?**

On the Mac with internet access, I would like to have packages such as `nvm`, `node`, `npm`, `wine32`, etc. to be installed on the Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) with no internet. The packages will be transferred via burned on a CD.

Usually how in Windows a user downloads an `.exe` and transports that file to another computer and install there, essentially that is what I want to replicate.

**What have I tried?**

I've seen the `https://packages.ubuntu.com` website but get confused on the architecture download part. There is no specification on what architecture to get. When I click on the links for a particular download, say `https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/i386/wine32/download`, the link goes nowhere for me. There is no download for me. Sometimes I see packages ending in `.deb` or `.tar.xz` and unsure of which one to download.

In order:

1. How do I properly get packages I need on the Mac to be ready to install on Linux? (Is there a proper website to use to download said packages or command line?)
2. How do I install it on Linux using the terminal? (I've read around to do `apt` or `dkpg`?)

Comment: Soft of, I was able to download and install, but now I'm running into dependency fest where I download `wine32`, but it needs 2 dependencies, and so on and so forth. Is there a way to download everything in 1 packaged `.deb` file or something similar? I don't want to keep downloading individual packages until it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the `--download-only` option with `apt`, which will include all of the dependencies required by packages. You will, however, need to first create a VM of 18.04 – ideally the very same version you've air-gapped – on your Mac.

The process would go something like this:

1. Create a VM of Ubuntu 18.04 on the Mac using VirtualBox or another tool of your choice
2. On the VM, open Terminal and download the packages you need:

   ```
   sudo apt --download-only -o Dir::Cache="/home/{user}/Downloads" \
    -o Dir::Cache::archives="./" install {package name}
   ```

   Although this will *look like* it's going to install the software, the `--download-only` option limits `apt` to just downloading the packages plus dependencies. The `Dir::Cache` option allows you to specify *where* you want the `.deb` files placed.
3. Once you've obtained all of the packages that you need, copy the files to a USB stick or optical disc and install them on the air-gapped system:

   ```
   sudo apt install /path/to/package.deb
   ```

This can be annoying the first time but, if you are regularly working with air-gapped systems, this option will allow you to create predictable and consistent installation media which will continue working long after a version of Ubuntu is no longer supported.