# Thinkpad T14s Gen 2 AMD - Ubuntu 21.10 - No wifi

Tags: wireless, thinkpad

I bought USB 3.0 to 10/100/1000 Mbps Gigabit RJ45 Ethernet LAN Adapter and use the internet to install the driver.

My laptop has no wifi. After searching on google I found this solution:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

But it has some requirements: "make", "gcc", "kernel headers", "kernel build essentials". I don't know how to install it to my ubuntu, because the laptop doesn't have internet.
I have USB and other internet computer, is there anyway to install these requirements offline?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the other computer also running Ubuntu — ideally the same version? If so, you can download all of the `.deb` files from the other machine for the `build-essentials` package, which is what you need 

Comment: Yes, my PC is running Ubuntu. How can I download all of the .deb files?

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1381213/1222991) will walk you through the process. You will want to replace `{package name}` with `build-essential`, which will download quite a large number of files. Copy them all to a USB stick and bring them over to the notebook.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed you link, but when I downloaded, it gives me file .bin instead of .deb

Comment: I got 2 files: pkgcache.bin and srcpkgcache.bin

Comment: are you sure that wifi is not switched off using physical switch or in bios?

Comment: There is no problem with physical switch. I'm not about bios, my laptop is new 100 with seal. how to check it in bios?

Comment: I have just check my bios:
https://i.imgur.com/ofAO1xY.jpg
I think it is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)